# Tikz node size too large

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm currently visualizing an expanding window training set (36 months), fixed test set (12 months) and validation/prediction set of 1 month. I have managed to fit 60 individual months on one page by scaling down the tikz image itself, but am now stuck on scaling down the node size.

The current image looks as follows.

[image]

It is a bit small but serves the purpose of what I am trying to achieve. However, as soon as the node numbering starts to go above ten, it looks weird because the spacing between the numbers starts messing up. Does anyone have a solution to this issue? My current code can be found below.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{environ}
\makeatletter
\newsavebox{\measure@tikzpicture}
\NewEnviron{scaletikzpicturetowidth}[1]{%
  \def\tikz@width{#1}%
  \def\tikzscale{1}\begin{lrbox}{\measure@tikzpicture}%
  \BODY
  \end{lrbox}%
  \pgfmathparse{#1/\wd\measure@tikzpicture}%
  \edef\tikzscale{\pgfmathresult}%
  \BODY
}
\makeatother

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\definecolor{myLightGray}{RGB}{191,191,191}
\definecolor{myGray}{RGB}{160,160,160}
\definecolor{myDarkGray}{RGB}{88,88,88}
\definecolor{myDarkRed}{RGB}{167,114,115}
\definecolor{myRed}{RGB}{255,58,70}
\definecolor{myGreen}{RGB}{0,255,71}

\begin{document}
\begin{scaletikzpicturetowidth}{\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale = \tikzscale]
% draw horizontal line   
\draw[->] (0,0) -- (60.7,0);

% draw vertical lines
\foreach \x in {0,1,...,60}{
    \draw (\x cm,8pt) -- (\x cm,0.5pt);
}

% place axis labels
\foreach \x in {0,1,...,60}{
    \node[anchor=north] at (\x,-1) {\tiny $\the\numexpr\x$};
}


% draw scale below
\foreach \x in {0,1,...,35}{
    \fill[myLightGray] (\x,-0.4) rectangle (\the\numexpr\x+1,-0.55);
}

\foreach \x in {36,37,...,47}{
    \fill[myDarkGray] (\x,-0.4) rectangle (\the\numexpr\x+1,-0.55);
}

\fill[myGreen] (48,-0.4) rectangle (49,-0.55);


% draw scale below
\foreach \x in {0,1,...,36}{
    \fill[myLightGray] (\x,-0.6) rectangle (\the\numexpr\x+1,-0.75);
}

\foreach \x in {37,38,...,48}{
    \fill[myDarkGray] (\x,-0.6) rectangle (\the\numexpr\x+1,-0.75);
}

\fill[myGreen] (49,-0.6) rectangle (50,-0.75);


% draw scale below
\foreach \x in {0,1,...,37}{
    \fill[myLightGray] (\x,-0.8) rectangle (\the\numexpr\x+1,-0.95);
}

\foreach \x in {38,39,...,49}{
    \fill[myDarkGray] (\x,-0.8) rectangle (\the\numexpr\x+1,-0.95);
}

\fill[myGreen] (50,-0.8) rectangle (51,-0.95);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{scaletikzpicturetowidth}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should give you everything you wanted I guess!

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{environ}
\makeatletter
\newsavebox{\measure@tikzpicture}
\NewEnviron{scaletikzpicturetowidth}[1]{%
  \def\tikz@width{#1}%
  \def\tikzscale{1}\begin{lrbox}{\measure@tikzpicture}%
  \BODY
  \end{lrbox}%
  \pgfmathparse{#1/\wd\measure@tikzpicture}%
  \edef\tikzscale{\pgfmathresult}%
  \BODY
}
\makeatother

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\definecolor{myLightGray}{RGB}{191,191,191}
\definecolor{myGray}{RGB}{160,160,160}
\definecolor{myDarkGray}{RGB}{88,88,88}
\definecolor{myDarkRed}{RGB}{167,114,115}
\definecolor{myRed}{RGB}{255,58,70}
\definecolor{myGreen}{RGB}{0,255,71}

\begin{document}
\begin{scaletikzpicturetowidth}{\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale = \tikzscale]
% draw horizontal line   
\draw[->] (0,0) -- (60.7,0);

% draw vertical lines
\foreach \x in {0,1,...,60}{
    \draw (\x cm,8pt) -- (\x cm,0.5pt);
}
% place axis labels
\node[anchor=north] at (0,1.6) {\tiny $0$};
\node[anchor=north] at (12,1.6) {\tiny $1\!2$};
\node[anchor=north] at (24,1.6) {\tiny $2\!4$};
\node[anchor=north] at (36,1.6) {\tiny $3\!6$};
\node[anchor=north] at (48,1.6) {\tiny $4\!8$};
\node[anchor=north] at (49,1.6) {\tiny $4\!9$};
\node[anchor=north] at (50,1.6) {\tiny $5\!0$};
\node[anchor=north] at (51,1.6) {\tiny $5\!1$};
\node[anchor=north] at (52,1.6) {\tiny $5\!2$};
\node[anchor=north] at (53,1.6) {\tiny $5\!3$};
\node[anchor=north] at (54,1.6) {\tiny $5\!4$};
\node[anchor=north] at (55,1.6) {\tiny $5\!5$};
\node[anchor=north] at (56,1.6) {\tiny $5\!6$};
\node[anchor=north] at (57,1.6) {\tiny $5\!7$};
\node[anchor=north] at (58,1.6) {\tiny $5\!8$};
\node[anchor=north] at (59,1.6) {\tiny $5\!9$};
\node[anchor=north] at (60,1.6) {\tiny $6\!0$};

% draw scale below
\foreach \x in {0,1,...,35}{
    \fill[myLightGray] (\x,-0.1) rectangle (\the\numexpr\x+1,-0.55);
}

\foreach \x in {36,37,...,47}{
    \fill[myDarkGray] (\x,-0.1) rectangle (\the\numexpr\x+1,-0.55);
}

\fill[myGreen] (48,-0.1) rectangle (49,-0.55);

% draw scale below
\foreach \x in {0,1,...,36}{
    \fill[myLightGray] (\x,-0.65) rectangle (\the\numexpr\x+1,-1.1);
}

\foreach \x in {37,38,...,48}{
    \fill[myDarkGray] (\x,-0.65) rectangle (\the\numexpr\x+1,-1.1);
}

\fill[myGreen] (49,-0.65) rectangle (50,-1.1);

% draw scale below
\foreach \x in {0,1,...,37}{
    \fill[myLightGray] (\x,-1.2) rectangle (\the\numexpr\x+1,-1.65);
}

\foreach \x in {38,39,...,49}{
    \fill[myDarkGray] (\x,-1.2) rectangle (\the\numexpr\x+1,-1.65);
}

\fill[myGreen] (50,-1.2) rectangle (51,-1.65);

\draw[decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=5pt}] (36,-2) -- (0,-2)
node[anchor=north,midway,below=4pt] {Training Set}; 

\draw[decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=5pt}] (48,-2) -- (36,-2)
    node[anchor=north,midway,below=4pt] {Test Set}; 

\draw [<-] (49,-0.35) -- (54,-0.35) -- (54,-2.6);]

\draw[white,decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=5pt}] (60,-2) -- (48,-2)
    node[text=black,anchor=north,midway,below=4pt] {Prediction}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{scaletikzpicturetowidth}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Looks great, just how I wanted it!